# Estimating how many spheres there are inside of a domain, only knowing one slide

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

Let $D$ be a domain, for example, a cylinder (like a glass of water) of height $H=500$, with circular base of radius $R=300$, which contains spheres (cells) with radius $r = 50\times 10^{-6}$ floating in a viscous liquid. $D$ is not full of spheres, but I know that the spheres are uniformly distributed (not in the mathematical sense).

We freeze $D$ and make a slide parallel to the base of $D$ with height $h=5\times 10^{-6}$ (the slide is like a coin with radius $R=300$ and height $h=5\times 10^{-6}$).  We can count the number of pieces (slides) of spheres contained inside the "coin" (of course, each slide of sphere inside the "coin" has different size).

**I need to estimate how many spheres there are inside of $D$, but I only have one slide of $D$.**

How can I estimate how many spheres there are in D? What mathematical tools can I apply? I thought infinitesimal calculus, but maybe some statistical tool is the most appropriate.

Comment: This can be done by elementary geometry and arithmetic. All that matters is the total number of slices, and the thickness of each slice compared to the size of the objects you're counting. I'd post an answer, but something about the wording suggests to me this is part of an assignment or test. In any case, the "solution energy" is significantly lower than the "statement energy"; I'm afraid this always raises uncharitable suspicions. Hoping the hints above help direct you toward an easy solution.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewD.Hwang for comment.  This is not an assignment or work, I promise. This problem  started in a conversation with a friend of mine. He has only some slides of a cells, and he want to calculate...    Here I tried to reduce the problem to something more comfortable for mathematicians, with some assumptions. For me it is not clear that the problem can be done with elementary arithmetic.

Comment: For me it is not clear that the problem is basic math.
Next I write my idea of solution.

With the radius of each **slide** of sphere in the "coin", estimate the sum of the volume of all slides of spheres in the coin $v_c$ (maybe, calculating this volumes using integrals, because are slides of spheres). I could define a density $d=\frac{v_c}{V_s}$, where $V_s$ is the volumen of the "coin". If I assume that this density is independent of the slide, then $d=\frac{v}{V}$, where $v$ and $V$ be the volume of all spheres and $D$, resp. With this I can calculate the solution, Which is your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count $n$ spheres hitting the single slice, there are about $(n/21) \times 10^{8}$ spheres in $D$.

Under the stated assumptions, $D$ is cut into $10^{8}$ slices. Since the density of spheres is uniform, you expect about $n \times 10^{8}$ pieces of sphere among all the slides. A single sphere, however, has a diameter about $20$ times the thickness of a slide, so each sphere hits (roughly) $21$ slides.

(If you can easily distinguish pieces of sphere that pierce the layer versus those that protrude only part way through, you should find about $2/21 \approx 9.5$% partial protrusions among all spherical pieces. That may serve as a useful check on the method.)